# Setting language for DirectionsService in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I now switched to the [v3 API of google maps](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) and offer some route-planning using google's `DirectionsService`. It all works as expected, but the language is in english and i can't find a way to set it to german. The map itself is already in german – only the output of `DirectionsService` is in english.

Anyone an idea how to set it to `de-DE`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a lot of googling i came along [a blogpost on google geodevelopers](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/10/maps-api-v3-now-speaks-your-language.html) that told me to simply put the language into the api-request request:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=de"></script>
```

And it works!

Comment: For languages with suffix, use locale code pt-br, en-us, es-ar

Answer (score 2):

Google maps will use the language specified in the user's browser in the `Accept-Language` header. You change this by doing what you found and adding the language to the url.

Comment: As mentioned the map was already in german, yet the output of DirectionsService in the Panel was still in english. Maybe it's a bug in the API…?